# How to get the sum of the value in the datagridview column using vb.net?

Tags: datagridview

I've used this code but it doesn't add the value. ! [i wanted to add the values in "amount" column but the output in the "total amount of donations" is not correct.   thanks for the help!

```
Private Sub donations_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Dim total As String = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To dondgv.RowCount - 1
        total += dondgv.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
    Next
    Label4.Text = total

 End Sub



End Class
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not enough information. Please edit the question and include what actual problem you are facing.